# How can I prevent powershell from treating YabaDabaDoo as an alias for Get-YabaDabaDoo?

Tags: powershell

Please, observe:

```
C:\> Get-Date

Tuesday, February 4, 2020 5:50:55 PM

C:\> Date

Tuesday, February 4, 2020 5:50:57 PM

C:\> Get-Content C:\Users\mkharitonov\.bashrc
alias ls='ls --color=auto -alhX'
alias npp="C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
C:\> Content C:\Users\mkharitonov\.bashrc
alias ls='ls --color=auto -alhX'
alias npp="C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
C:\>
```

I do not want this behavior. How can one control it?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this question. Makes perfect sense, so why all the down-votes? (Especially rude when not providing the user any feedback.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of PowerShell Core 7.3.2, you *cannot* prevent this behavior, which is by (costly) design: **`Get` is the *implied* default verb**, so submitting `Content` ultimately invokes `Get-Content`, for instance - unless a command explicitly named `Content` exists too.

A member of the PowerShell team has openly [considered removing this feature](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3987#issuecomment-308279494), given that it is both obscure and costly in terms of performance (in addition to being incompletely implemented):

> Note that this command lookup behavior is not limited to cmdlets - it works for any command including native commands.
>
> It is also very expensive - we first search normally (including the PATH), and if that fails, we repeat the search prepending `Get-`.
>
> Personally, I'd rather remove this misfeature than formalize it.
> We could provide a handler for `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.CommandNotFoundAction` for folks that are unwilling to fix old scripts that rely on this odd feature.

Comment: Any way to disable it for PS 5.1 ?

Comment: I don't think so, @mark. You could consider opening a feature request for the feature's _future_ removal, though.