# How do I trim the output of a command?

Tags: powershell, trim

I have the following code that grabs the full name associated with the microsoft account.
It technically works but there should be a way to do it succinctly without redefining the variable.

```
$fullName = Net User $Env:username | Select-String -Pattern "Full Name";$fullName = ("$fullName").TrimStart("Full Name")
```

Comment: Try `$fullName = (Get-LocalUser -Name $env:USERNAME).FullName`

Comment: Or `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name='$env:USERNAME'").FullName`

Comment: Or even (slower) `([adsi]"WinNT://$($env:COMPUTERNAME)/$($env:Username),user").FullName[0]`

Comment: I appreciate you, seeing all variations is helpful

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that `Net User` returns LOCALIZED text, so trying to parse for `Full Name` would in my case (Dutch computer) not find anything because for me it is called `Volledige naam`. The methods above don't have that handicap.

Comment: imagine being so f**** smart you are providing this level of help and its not even your native language. Legend.

Comment: Blush.. Probably because I'm not on an English computer, I run into these localized pitfalls and so I need to find my way around them.

Comment: @theo so the property name in wmi isn't localized?

Comment: @js2010 Indeed, the property names are English.

Answer (score 1):

Before trim:

```
net user $env:username | findstr 'Full Name'

Full Name                    The Admin
```

Using the version of foreach-object or % that runs a method with an argument.  Note TrimStart() is case sensitive.

```
net user $env:username | findstr 'Full Name' | % trimstart Full` Name

The Admin
```

Select-object would have the string in a Line property.

```
net user $env:username | select-string 'Full Name' | % { $_.line.
  trimstart('Full Name') }

The Admin
```

Or take select-string's output in a string context:

```
net user $env:username | select-string 'Full Name' | 
  % { "$_".trimstart('Full Name') }

The Admin
```

Or just get-localuser and the fullname property:

```
localuser $env:username | % fullname

The Admin
```

Another demo of how trimstart works; each letter is taken by itself and the order doesn't matter:

```
'FFNNuuee  hi there' | % trimstart 'Full Name'

hi there
```

Comment: Nice, but relying on PowerShell's little-used default-verb feature (e.g., using `localuser` to invoke `Get-LocalUser`) is best avoided, due to its obscurity, potential ambiguity, and performance implications - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067030/45375) for details.