# Minimal Powershell script with Process block gives system process list (MacOS, Pwsh 7.1.3)

Tags: powershell

I was writing a Powershell script using a pipeline with a `Process` block and it started doing something unexpected: listing all the running processes and then dumping the script contents.  I kept minimizing the script to try to figure out what was going on and ended up with this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
$varname = "huh"

Process
{
    # nothing here
}
```

So it looks like this:

```
PS /Volumes/folder> cat ./test.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
$varname = "huh"

Process
{
    # nothing here
}
PS /Volumes/folder> pwsh ./test.ps1

 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00       0 639 
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00       1   1 
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00      60  60 
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00      61  61 
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00      65  65 
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00      67  67 
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00      68  68 
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00      69  69 
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00      71  71 
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00      73  73 
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00      75  75 
      0     0.00      25.60      75.82   68475   1 Activity Monito
      0     0.00      11.74      97.63    1053   1 Adobe Crash Han
      0     0.00      11.76      97.62    1084   1 Adobe Crash Han
      0     0.00      11.69      97.64    1392   1 Adobe Crash Han
      0     0.00     112.50      83.59     973   1 Adobe Desktop S
      0     0.00      11.94      97.31     986   1 AdobeCRDaemon
      0     0.00      16.95     105.99     966   1 AdobeIPCBroker
      0     0.00      61.52     168.92     721   1 Adobe_CCXProces
      0     0.00      18.57       3.01     454   1 adprivacyd
      0     0.00      16.46      23.16     700   1 AGMService
      0     0.00      13.65       4.43     701   1 AirPlayUIAgent
   --snip--
      0     0.00       9.11      12.72   89003 …03 VTDecoderXPCSer
      0     0.00      13.32       4.69     418   1 WiFiAgent
      0     0.00      12.21       1.58     543 543 WiFiProxy

    # nothing here
```

I haven't done much in Powershell for a long time so if this is something stupid simple I'm going to laugh but I couldn't find anything searching the net.

Can someone tell me what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In order to use a `process` block** (possibly alongside a `begin`, `end`, and, in v7.3+, the `clean` block), **there *must not be any code OUTSIDE these blocks*** - see the conceptual [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions) help topic.

Therefore, remove `$varname = "huh"` from the top-level scope of your function body (possibly move it into one of the aforementioned blocks).

---

As for **what you tried**:

- By having `$varname = "huh"` in the top-level scope of your function body, you've effectively made the function in one whose code runs in an *implicit* `end` block only.
- `process` - because it is on its own line - was then interpreted as a *command*, which - due to the [best-avoided default-verb logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067030/45375) - was interpreted as an argument-less call to the [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) cmdlet.

  - The output therefore included the list of all processes on your system.
- The `{ ... }` on the subsequent lines was then interpreted as a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) literal. Since that script block wasn't *invoked*, it was *implicitly output*, which results in its *stringification*, which is its _verbatim content, excluding `{` and `}`, resulting in output of the following string:

```
# nothing here
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the thorough explanation of all these different aspects.  At one point when I was fiddling with this I did think that maybe somehow `process` was getting interpreted as `get-process` but when I typed `process` on the command line it didn't produce a process list (`Missing statement after 'process'`).  That's probably a DIFFERENT SA question! ;)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @AndyJ. On the command line, submitting _just_ `process` seemingly _is_ interpreted as an attempt define a `process` _block_, but if you precede it with another command (as in your script), you'll see the symptom. E.g. `'dummy command'; process`

Comment: Ha, you're right, that's interesting.  Good learning experience, thanks again!